# SQL Agent Job Dependency Scheduling

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have the following scenario that I'm trying to solve in SQL Agent.

Job 2 needs to kick off @ 1AM, but has a dependency on Job 1.

I've been trying to figure out if there is a way to schedule a specific step? That way instead of having a Job 2 I could have step 2 dependent on step 1 and have it scheduled for a later time.

Alternatively, I know that I could build a table to determine dependency. Similar to [SQL Server Agent job dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229374/sql-server-agent-job-dependency).
However, I'm looking to make it intelligent enough that if Job 1 isn't finished yet by the scheduled time Job 2 will try to run again at a later interval.

Comment: Are you familiar with `sp_getapplock`? You could specify your own semaphore and if you get it, you continue on. If you don't get the semaphore, you exit gracefully (only to try again later).

Comment: I am not familiar. I will have to take a look. Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different approaches.

**The one is**

1) Create the last step in Job 1 to start Job 2

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'enter you job name here'
```

2) The first step of Job 2 should be TSQL command

```
WIATFOR DELAY xx:yy:zz
```

xx,yy,zz values should be calculated as time difference between now and required 1AM.

If NOW() is greater then 1AM, exit (complete) the step 1 to execute step 2 immediately.

Note that Job 2 in this case should not be scheduled.

**Another method**:

In Job 2, the first step in WHILE loop checks the status of job 1 (the code can be found easily online) with some delay, e.g. 1 minute. The loop exit condition is when Job 1 is complete.

Comment: Thanks Anton for the ideas. I'm going to do some testing and see how it works out. Although just reading through it they seem like very promising options!

Answer (score 0):

If you create step 1 in your first SQL Agent Job as the last step (this)

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'enter you job name here'
```

Then you don't need a step 2 in your second SQL Agent Job (this)

```
WIATFOR DELAY xx:yy:zz
```

In fact, you don't even need to add a schedule to your second SQL Agent Job, the step at the end of Step 1 will just run the SQL Agent Job for you.